# Not expected hover effects in tailwind in menu

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am applying tailwind in vue to build a navigation.

```
 <div class="px-2 w-56">
    <div class="bg-[#dce3ef40] rounded-lg my-2">
       <ul class="space-y-0">

          <li v-for="item in solutions" :key="item.name" :href="item.href" class="px-4 py-2 flex space-x-4   items-center hover:bg-indigo-100 cursor-pointer" :class="selectedNav==item.name ? 'font-bold text-gray-100 bg-[#0175f6]' : '' ">
             <div v-html="item.icon"></div> 
             <a href="#">{{ item.name }}</a>
          </li>

       </ul>
    </div>

 </div>
```

the effects can be seen here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/8p7VnSbmEl
This is what the menu looks like as [image]

the hover effects on the selected menu item is like this.
[image]

What I expect is the hover can only work for the non-selected item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `pointer-events-none` utility class on the selected element. By using it you can prevent any hover effects from being triggered on the active element in your menu. Also, if you want the hover effects to be re-enabled when the active state changes, you should revert the pointer-events property to its default value with the `pointer-events-auto` utility class.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.8/vue.global.min.js"></script>
<div class="px-2 w-56">
  <div class="bg-[#dce3ef40] rounded-lg my-2">
    <ul class="space-y-0">
      <li 
        v-for="item in solutions" 
        :key="item.name" 
        :href="item.href" 
        class="px-4 py-2 flex space-x-4   items-center hover:bg-indigo-100 cursor-pointer"
        :class="selectedNav==item.name ? 'font-bold text-gray-100 bg-[#0175f6] pointer-events-none' : 'pointer-events-auto'">
        <div v-html="item.icon"></div>
        <a href="#">{{ item.name }}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```